# Putting a variable outside or inside a method scope within an update loop

Tags: java, c++

This applies to both C and JAVA I'm asking for both.

I've got an update loop that's runs maybe a few hundred times a second indefinably.

My concerns are mainly memory management and what happens.

Here's the example so

```
public methodA(double Delta)
{
    double doubleTest = Delta;
    SomeObject newObject = new Object(Delta);
}

SomeObject newObject = new Object();
double doubleTest;
public methodB(double Delta)
{
    doubleTest = Delta;
    newObject.setUpdate(Delta);
}
```

Now I know in JAVA that the methodA is GC'ed at the cost of performance but what exactly happens in C or C++? Do variables or objects declared within the method scope get destoryed? If so which loop is better? (Would we be getting out of memory with the second loop?)

Also is it really worth pre-creating the object for the method update? What's the performance gain if any?

Comment: In C++, new in a loop leaks memory, there is no GC in C/C++

Comment: Also, there are no `new` or member functions in C (although you can write equivalent code).

Comment: I don't see any loops in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**  - The variables get destroyed.

**2.** - Second, if you're passing in a parameter, it does not need to be outside the method scope.

**3.** - It would be more efficient from a writing-perspective to put it all in one line.  The memory footprint is very minimal between the two, if any.

Answer (score 0):

1. Methods aren't garbage-collected.
2. I don't see any loops in your code, so I'm confused about what you are asking.
3. Your two methods do very different things, and so comparing them is difficult. First of all, compilers are very smart these days (Java, C, and C++). Unless Object's constructor has side effects, a reasonable compiler would probably optimize away all calls to `methodA` anyways, since it does nothing.

   `methodB` does something completely different than `methodA`, so I'm not sure why you are comparing the two. `methodB` calls `newObject.setUpdate()`, which, presuming it has a side effect, will not be removed by the compiler. Of course, if you never actually use `newObject` anywhere else, the compiler may still determine that it is unnecessary and optimize away all calls to `methodB`.

In any case, your question is confusing to me because I'm not sure what you are specifically trying to compare.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know in JAVA that the methodA is GC'ed at the cost of
>   performance but what exactly happens in C or C++? Do variables or
>   objects declared within the method scope get destoryed? If so which
>   loop is better? (Would we be getting out of memory with the second
>   loop?)

There is no concept of method being garbage collected, only references are garbage collected.
Local variables scope is limited to the method/function they are defined in for both Java and c++. But there is an exception to it in c++, if you are creating dynamic data structure using malloc/calloc then the memory of that variable will not freed until you don't explicitly do so. There is no garbage collector in C++ so you need to be careful about dyamic memory allocation and to free that memory. This responsibility lies with the developer in C++, whereas in Java , JVM garbage collector takes care of it.